# Is Intellij IDEA obsolete like Eclipse for Android development?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Google officially [announced](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) that Eclipse should no longer be used for Android development and we should move to Android Studio.

Does the same apply to IntelliJ IDEA? I have multiple projects in Eclipse format which will not be ported to Gradle yet, so I am not sure if I can use IntelliJ IDEA for maintaining those project.

I was unable to find anything official about IntelliJ IDEA after Android Studio became stable so I suspected that nothing has changed with it (it's the only issue with ADT and support for ADT).

Note: I am using IntelliJ IDEA right now, as I have been using it for 3 years, and so far I have not faced any issues with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to move your Android Projects from IntelliJ IDEA to Android Studio since they are both developped by JetBrains and Android Studio come from IntelliJ IDEA platform.

You can find more details on the [IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio FAQ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/).

Here's a quote from this FAQ :

> **If I’m already a user of IntelliJ IDEA, do I need to switch to Android Studio for Android development?**
>
> No. Android Studio is focused specifically on Android development and
>   provides streamlined environment and project setup, but otherwise all
>   of its features are available in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

[Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), so that won't happen until Android Studio is deprecated itself

Comment: Yes, they use IDEA's Android plugin. Just hoping to get something official from IDEA's representative. I know they are watching Starckoverlow.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [faq](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/). Short answer - yes, it's ok to use IntelliJ with Android plugin for development. Also have a look at Android page on Intellij site [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/android.html).

> Being the most intelligent IDE for Java IntelliJ IDEA provides
>   out-of-the-box Android support that includes intelligent coding
>   assistance, for professional development of Android applications.
>   Android support is available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and IntelliJ
>   IDEA Community Edition.